# Make dynamically generated Textblocks to fit to their respective content

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-store-apps

I am making a Windows 8 app and I am displaying words in dynamically generated textblocks using gridview. I want each textblock to be of the exact width so as to fit to the respective word contained in it. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: `Is there a way to do this?` - Yes, I'm pretty sure there's a way for whatever you're trying to do. Please read [**this**](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: The default `TextBlock` `Auto` `Width` should do this already, plus some `Padding` around it that built into the `Style`. The drawn width/height will change based on the `Horizontal` and `VerticalAlignment` though, so if you've tried it already and are coming across problems, this may be why. Plus, the `GridViewItem`s have their own padding, which you can also remove using a custom `Style`. You can view the default `Style` for `GridViewItem`s [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709915.aspx). (Scroll down a bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried generating textblocks in the codebehind dynamically and added text. The width of the resulting blocks was fitting the content.
So as soon as one dynamically generates text-blocks, they automatically fit to the content width.